# Why the difference between octave's prctile and numpy's percentile?

Tags: numpy, octave

I've been rewriting a matlab/octave program into numpy and ran across a difference in some resultant values.
This occurs with both the percentile/prctile and the stdard-deviation functions.

In Numpy:

```
import matplotlib.mlab as ml
import numpy

>>> t = numpy.linspace(0,100, 100)
>>> numpy.percentile(t,95)
95.0
>>> numpy.std(t)
29.157646512850626
>>> ml.prctile(t,95)
95.000000000000014
```

In Octave:

```
octave:1> t = linspace(0,100,100)';
octave:2> prctile(t,95)
ans =  95.454545
octave:3> std(t)
ans =  29.304537
```

Although the array values of 't' are the same, the results are more different than I would suspect.

In the numpy help(numpy.std) they specifically mention that the algorithm is:

```
std = sqrt(mean(abs(x - x.mean())**2))
```

So I implemented that in octave and got the exact answer numpy gives.  So it seems the std-deviation function differs.
But why/how? And which is correct? (if there is such a thing)

And even prctile/percentile?

Just in case since I'm in Linux aptosid...

GNU Octave, version 3.6.2

numpy.**version** '1.6.2rc1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy simply uses a different algorithm when the percentile lies between two data points. Octave, Matlab and R always center it exactly between two points when needed (I believe), numpy does a bit more then that... if you check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile you will see there are a couple of ways to calculate percentiles.

Comment: Yes, and even there, octave comes up with 95.450 which leads me to believe that numpy is being more 'correct' at 95.000.

Comment: Sorry, I guess that 101 thing was wrong... but still numpy does more complex stuff here, and for sure not wrong.

Comment: With t=linspace(0,100,N), regardless of N, numpy figures the 95th percentile as 95, but octave varies somewhat wrt N.  Weird.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Octave assumes ddof=1, at least by default, and numpy uses 0 by default:

```
>>> numpy.std(t, ddof=0)
29.157646512850633
>>> numpy.std(t, ddof=1)
29.304537349375785
```

Comment: Thanks for that!  That certainly clears up the std-deviation question!